# How does .forEach actuallly work with something that isn't an array

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, foreach

I've been doing some research on `.forEach` as when I use it, to my understanding, it is used to do something to each element in an array. For something which isn't an array, it seems to do nothing and could be replaced with just a function. I'll attach a program where I can't work out what the `btn.forEach` does and why it's that and not just a function without the `.forEach`. When I try to google it, it says that it can only be used with arrays, or gives examples with them, but never with just a variable, etc.

```js
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
const storeItem = document.querySelectorAll('.store-item');
const doughnut = document.querySelectorAll('.doughnuts');
const sweets = document.querySelectorAll('.sweets');
const cakes = document.querySelectorAll('.cakes');
const cupcakes = document.querySelectorAll('.cupcakes');

btn.forEach(function(btn){
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault()

        const filter = e.target.dataset.filter 

        if (filter == 'all'){
            storeItem.forEach(function(item){
                item.style.display = 'block'
            })
        } else if (filter == 'cakes'){
            storeItem.forEach(function(item){
                if (item.classList.contains('cakes')){
                    item.style.display = 'block'
                } else {
                    item.style.display = 'none'
                }
            }) 
        } else if (filter == 'doughnuts'){
            storeItem.forEach(function(item){
                if (item.classList.contains('doughnuts')){
                    item.style.display = 'block'
                } else {
                    item.style.display = 'none'
                }
            }) 
        } else if (filter == 'sweets'){
            storeItem.forEach(function(item){
                if (item.classList.contains('sweets')){
                    item.style.display = 'block'
                } else {
                    item.style.display = 'none'
                }
            }) 
        } else if (filter == 'cupcakes'){
            storeItem.forEach(function(item){
                if (item.classList.contains('cupcakes')){
                    item.style.display = 'block'
                } else {
                    item.style.display = 'none'
                }
            }) 
        }
    });
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script");

:root {
  --mainPink: #ef7998;
  --mainYellow: rgb(249, 228, 148);
  --mainWhite: #fff;
  --mainBlack: #000;
  --yellowTrans: rgba(249, 228, 148, 0.5);
  --mainGrey: rgb(238, 238, 238);
}

body {
  font-family: "Kaushan Script", cursive;
  background: var(--mainWhite);
  color: var(--mainBlack);
}
/* nav links */
.navbar-toggler {
  outline: none !important;
}
.toggler-icon {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: var(--mainPink);
}
.nav-link {
  color: var(--mainPink);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.nav-link:hover {
  color: var(--mainBlack);
}
/* end of nav links */
/* info icons */
.cart-info__icon {
  color: var(--mainBlack);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cart-info {
  border: 0.1rem solid var(--mainBlack);
  color: var(--mainBlack);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  padding: 0.4rem 0.6rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.cart-info:hover {
  background: var(--mainPink);
  border-color: var(--mainPink);
  color: var(--mainWhite);
}
.cart-info:hover .cart-info__icon {
  color: var(--mainWhite);
}
/* end of info icons */
/* banner */

.max-height {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 76px);
  background: linear-gradient(var(--yellowTrans), var(--yellowTrans)),
    url("../img/headerBcg.jpeg") center/cover fixed no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}
.banner {
  color: var(--mainWhite);
  margin-top: -4rem;
}
.banner-title {
  color: var(--mainPink);
  font-size: 4rem;
}
.banner-link {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: var(--mainBlack);
  border: 0.2rem solid var(--mainBlack);
}
.banner-link:hover {
  background: var(--mainBlack);
  color: var(--mainPink);
}
/* endo of banner */
/* cart  */
.cart {
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 10rem;
  background: var(--mainWhite);
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.show-cart {
  width: 18rem;
  padding: 2rem 1.5rem;
  transform: rotateY(-360deg);
}
.cart-item {
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}

/* end of cart */
/* cart item */
.cart-item-remove {
  color: var(--mainPink);
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.cart-item-remove:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  color: var(--mainBlack);
}
#cart-item-price {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
/* cart item */
/* cart buttons */
.btn-pink {
  color: var(--mainPink) !important;
  border-color: var(--mainPink) !important;
}
.btn-black {
  color: var(--mainBlack) !important;
  border-color: var(--mainBlack) !important;
}
.btn-black:hover {
  color: var(--mainPink) !important;
  background: var(--mainBlack) !important;
}
.btn-pink:hover {
  background: var(--mainPink) !important;
  color: var(--mainBlack) !important;
}
/* end of cart buttons */

/* about */
.about-img__container {
  position: relative;
}

.about-img__container::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.5rem;
  left: -1.7rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  outline: 0.5rem solid var(--mainYellow);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.about-img__container:hover:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

/*end of  about */

/* store items */
.store {
  background: var(--mainGrey);
}
.img-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.store-img {
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.img-container:hover .store-img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
.store-item-icon {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  background: var(--mainYellow);
  border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transform: translate(100%, 100%);
}
.img-container:hover .store-item-icon {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.store-item-icon:hover {
  color: var(--mainWhite);
}
.store-item-value {
  color: --mainYellow;
}
/*end of  store items */
.search-box {
  background: var(--mainPink);
  color: var(--mainBlack);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <!-- bootstrap css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- main css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <!-- font awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="all.css">
  <title>Starter Template</title>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- header -->
  <header>
    <!-- navbar  -->
    <!-- 
https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/2427887/dessert_donut_doughnut_fat_sweets_icon
Creative Commons (Attribution 3.0 Unported);
https://www.iconfinder.com/korawan_m
     -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg px-4">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.svg" alt=""></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNav">
        <span class="toggler-icon"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto text-capitalize">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link " href="#">about</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">store</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="nav-info-items d-none d-lg-flex ">
          <!-- single info -->
          <div class="nav-info align-items-center d-flex justify-content-between mx-lg-5">
            <span class="info-icon mx-lg-3"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i></span>
            <p class="mb-0">+ 123 456 789</p>
          </div>
          <!-- end of single info -->
          <!-- single info -->
          <div id="cart-info" class="nav-info align-items-center cart-info d-flex justify-content-between mx-lg-5">
            <span class="cart-info__icon mr-lg-3"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></span>
            <p class="mb-0 text-capitalize"><span id="item-count">2 </span> items - $<span class="item-total">10.49</span></p>
          </div>
          <!-- end of single info -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- end of nav -->
    <!-- banner  -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row max-height justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col-10 mx-auto banner text-center">
          <h1 class="text-capitalize">welcome to <strong class="banner-title ">grandma's</strong></h1>
          <a href="#store" class="btn banner-link text-uppercase my-2">explore</a>

        </div>
        <div id="cart" class="cart">
          <!-- cart item -->
          <div class="cart-item d-flex justify-content-between text-capitalize my-3">
            <img src="img/z-cake-2.jpeg" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" id="item-img" alt="">
            <div class="item-text">

              <p id="cart-item-title" class="font-weight-bold mb-0">cart item</p>
              <p id="cart-item-price" class="mb-0">10.99</p>
            </div>
            <a href="#" id='cart-item-remove' class="cart-item-remove">
              <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
          <!--end of  cart item -->
          <!-- cart item -->
          <div class="cart-item d-flex justify-content-between text-capitalize my-3">
            <img src="img/z-sweets-3.jpeg" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" id="item-img" alt="">
            <div class="cart-item-text">

              <p id="cart-item-title" class="font-weight-bold mb-0">cart item</p>
              <p id="cart-item-price" class="mb-0">10.99</p>
            </div>
            <a href="#" id='cart-item-remove' class="cart-item-remove">
              <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
          <!--end of  cart item -->
          <!-- cart total -->
          <div class="cart-total-container d-flex justify-content-around text-capitalize mt-5">
            <h5>total</h5>
            <h5> $ <strong id="cart-total" class="font-weight-bold">10.00</strong> </h5>
          </div>
          <!--end cart total -->
          <!-- cart buttons -->
          <div class="cart-buttons-container mt-3 d-flex justify-content-between">
            <a href="#" id="clear-cart" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-black text-uppercase">clear cart</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary text-uppercase btn-pink">checkout</a>
          </div>
          <!--end of  cart buttons -->
          <!--  -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>




    <!--end of  banner  -->
  </header>
  <!-- header -->
  <!-- about us -->
  <section class="about py-5" id="about">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10 mx-auto col-md-6 my-5">
          <h1 class="text-capitalize">about <strong class="banner-title ">us</strong></h1>
          <p class="my-4 text-muted w-75">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, aliquam voluptas
            beatae vitae expedita consectetur nesciunt quia deserunt asperiores facere fuga dicta fugiat corrupti et omnis
            porro at dolorum! Ad!</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-black text-uppercase ">explore</a>

        </div>
        <div class="col-10 mx-auto col-md-6 align-self-center my-5">
          <div class="about-img__container">
            <img src="img/sweets-1.jpeg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- end of about us -->


  <!-- store -->
  <section id="store" class="store py-5">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- section title -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10 mx-auto col-sm-6 text-center">
          <h1 class="text-capitalize">our <strong class="banner-title ">store</strong></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end of section title -->
      <!--filter buttons -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-lg-8 mx-auto d-flex justify-content-around my-2 sortBtn flex-wrap">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-black text-uppercase filter-btn m-2" data-filter="all"> all</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-black text-uppercase filter-btn m-2" data-filter="cakes">cakes</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-black text-uppercase filter-btn m-2" data-filter="cupcakes">cupcakes</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-black text-uppercase filter-btn m-2" data-filter="sweets">sweets</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-black text-uppercase filter-btn m-2" data-filter="doughnuts">doughnuts</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- search box -->
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-10 mx-auto col-md-6">
          <form>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-prepend ">
                <span class="input-group-text search-box" id="search-icon"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></span>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder='item....' id="search-item">
            </div>

          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--end of filter buttons -->
      <!-- store  items-->
      <div class="row" id="store-items">
        <!-- single item -->
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mx-auto my-3 store-item sweets" data-item="sweets">
          <div class="card ">
            <div class="img-container">
              <img src="img/sweets-1.jpeg" class="card-img-top store-img" alt="">
              <span class="store-item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between text-capitalize">
                <h5 id="store-item-name">sweet item</h5>
                <h5 class="store-item-value">$ <strong id="store-item-price" class="font-weight-bold">5</strong></h5>

              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <!-- end of card-->
        </div>
        <!--end of single store item-->
        <!-- single item -->
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mx-auto my-3 store-item cupcakes" data-item="cupcakes">
          <div class="card ">
            <div class="img-container">
              <img src="img/cupcake-1.jpeg" class="card-img-top store-img" alt="">
              <span class="store-item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between text-capitalize">
                <h5 id="store-item-name">cupcake item</h5>
                <h5 class="store-item-value">$ <strong id="store-item-price" class="font-weight-bold">5</strong></h5>

              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <!-- end of card-->
        </div>
        <!--end of single store item-->
        <!-- single item -->
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mx-auto my-3 store-item cakes" data-item="cakes">
          <div class="card ">
            <div class="img-container">
              <img src="img/cake-1.jpeg" class="card-img-top store-img" alt="">
              <span class="store-item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between text-capitalize">
                <h5 id="store-item-name">cake item</h5>
                <h5 class="store-item-value">$ <strong id="store-item-price" class="font-weight-bold">5</strong></h5>

              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <!-- end of card-->
        </div>
        <!--end of single store item-->
        <!-- single item -->
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mx-auto my-3 store-item doughnuts" data-item="dougnuts">
          <div class="card ">
            <div class="img-container">
              <img src="img/doughnut-1.jpeg" class="card-img-top store-img" alt="">
              <span class="store-item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between text-capitalize">
                <h5 id="store-item-name">dougnut item</h5>
                <h5 class="store-item-value">$ <strong id="store-item-price" class="font-weight-bold">5</strong></h5>

              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <!-- end of card-->
        </div>
        <!--end of single store item-->
        <!-- single item -->
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mx-auto my-3 store-item sweets" data-item="sweets">
          <div class="card ">
            <div class="img-container">
              <img src="img/sweets-2.jpeg" class="card-img-top store-img" alt="">
              <span class="store-item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between text-capitalize">
                <h5 id="store-item-name">sweet item</h5>
                <h5 class="store-item-value">$ <strong id="store-item-price" class="font-weight-bold">10</strong></h5>

              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <!-- end of card-->
        </div>
        <!--end of single store item-->
        <!-- single item -->
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mx-auto my-3 store-item cupcakes" data-item="cupcakes">
          <div class="card ">
            <div class="img-container">
              <img src="img/cupcake-2.jpeg" class="card-img-top store-img" alt="">
              <span class="store-item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between text-capitalize">
                <h5 id="store-item-name">cupcake item</h5>
                <h5 class="store-item-value">$ <strong id="store-item-price" class="font-weight-bold">10</strong></h5>

              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <!-- end of card-->
        </div>
        <!--end of single store item-->
        <!-- single item -->
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mx-auto my-3 store-item cakes" data-item="cakes">
          <div class="card ">
            <div class="img-container">
              <img src="img/cake-2.jpeg" class="card-img-top store-img" alt="">
              <span class="store-item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between text-capitalize">
                <h5 id="store-item-name">cake item</h5>
                <h5 class="store-item-value">$ <strong id="store-item-price" class="font-weight-bold">10</strong></h5>

              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <!-- end of card-->
        </div>
        <!--end of single store item-->
        <!-- single item -->
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mx-auto my-3 store-item doughnuts" data-item="dougnuts">
          <div class="card ">
            <div class="img-container">
              <img src="img/doughnut-2.jpeg" class="card-img-top store-img" alt="">
              <span class="store-item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between text-capitalize">
                <h5 id="store-item-name">dougnut item</h5>
                <h5 class="store-item-value">$ <strong id="store-item-price" class="font-weight-bold">10</strong></h5>

              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <!-- end of card-->
        </div>
        <!--end of single store item-->
        <!-- single item -->
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mx-auto my-3 store-item sweets" data-item="sweets">
          <div class="card ">
            <div class="img-container">
              <img src="img/sweets-3.jpeg" class="card-img-top store-img" alt="">
              <span class="store-item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between text-capitalize">
                <h5 id="store-item-name">sweet item</h5>
                <h5 class="store-item-value">$ <strong id="store-item-price" class="font-weight-bold">15</strong></h5>

              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <!-- end of card-->
        </div>
        <!--end of single store item-->
        <!-- single item -->
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mx-auto my-3 store-item cupcakes" data-item="cupcakes">
          <div class="card ">
            <div class="img-container">
              <img src="img/cupcake-3.jpeg" class="card-img-top store-img" alt="">
              <span class="store-item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between text-capitalize">
                <h5 id="store-item-name">cupcake item</h5>
                <h5 class="store-item-value">$ <strong id="store-item-price" class="font-weight-bold">15</strong></h5>

              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <!-- end of card-->
        </div>
        <!--end of single store item-->
        <!-- single item -->
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mx-auto my-3 store-item cakes" data-item="cakes">
          <div class="card ">
            <div class="img-container">
              <img src="img/cake-3.jpeg" class="card-img-top store-img" alt="">
              <span class="store-item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between text-capitalize">
                <h5 id="store-item-name">cake item</h5>
                <h5 class="store-item-value">$ <strong id="store-item-price" class="font-weight-bold">15</strong></h5>

              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <!-- end of card-->
        </div>
        <!--end of single store item-->
        <!-- single item -->
        <div class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mx-auto my-3 store-item doughnuts" data-item="dougnuts">
          <div class="card ">
            <div class="img-container">
              <img src="img/doughnut-3.jpeg" class="card-img-top store-img" alt="">
              <span class="store-item-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between text-capitalize">
                <h5 id="store-item-name">dougnut item</h5>
                <h5 class="store-item-value">$ <strong id="store-item-price" class="font-weight-bold">15</strong></h5>

              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <!-- end of card-->
        </div>
        <!--end of single store item-->

      </div>
  </section>
  <!--end of store items -->



  <!-- jquery -->
  <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- bootstrap js -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <!-- script js -->
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it does nothing". It does the same thing -- it calls the function for every element of the array-like object.

Comment: `addEventListener()` can only be called on a single element, not a collection. So you have to use `forEach()` to call it on each element matched by the selector.

Comment: It can be used with any type that implements the method. `querySelectorAll()` returns a `NodeList`, and this also has a `forEach()` method. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Comment: *"it say's that it can only be used with **arrays** or gives example with them but never with **just a variable** etc."* - Your **variable** `btn` is a `NodeList`, which is an **array-like list** of `class="btn"` elements from your HTML. `.forEach()` is looping (iterating) each of those elements and, in your case, adding an `eventListener` for each other them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Comment: despite what have already been said here, you should utilize a `switch` case instead of so many `else if`-statements which perform slowly compared to a switch. Then use a `ternary conditional operator` instead of so many `else/if` statements nested within: `item.style.display = (item.classList.contains('cupcakes')) ? 'block' : 'none' ;`

Comment: @TimLewis thank you that clears it up for me

Comment: @tacoshy yeah that answers what my follow up question was going to be about in regards to query selectors and this thanks so much

Comment: I would expect you could use `.forEach` on anything that is [_iterable_](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols), however that is not stated in the specification and may not be true. Only things that are listed with `*.prototype.forEach` can _definitely_ be used with forEach. You can find those from a [search on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=forEach) or going to the [specifiction](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/) and searaching for forEach in your browser.